# Determination of solid bed fluidisation

Tags: fluid-mechanics, chemical-engineering, compressible-flow, multiphase-flow

How would one determine if a fluidised bed (with liquid flow) is determined to be a stable fluidised bed, which subsequently doesn't form a plug or bed at the top of a column (bounded by frits), when under pressure?

Answer (score 1):

Use flow (which is a product of pressure).

If a single solid will be entrained at the flow rate then it will plug.

If the bed has a packing factor of 50% then flow velocity in the bed is twice pipe flow velocity. As the bed fluidizes the packing factor goes down as does flow velocity.

VelocityPacking = VelocityPipe / (1 - packing)

The smaller particles will be lost (plug) first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you mean flow in the bed should be set to double the standard pipe flow, assuming no packing,  or that at a flow rate x, the experienced bed flow will be 2x?